# Segmentation fault, and passing in pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

When running the code below, I am getting a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

I've been told that seg faults are likely due to bad pointers most of the time. Now, I am relatively new to the language and with that being said I'm sure I doing something obviously wrong here but can't spot it due to my inexperience and current level of proficiency.

The code below is creating a `vector` of `PeekDeque<StringWrap>` objects in the `main` method. It then passes a pointer to the `vector` to the function `testNewWord`. This function then creates a new `PeekDeque<StringWrap>` object and then pushes it to the back of the `vector`. Well, that's what I'm trying to do anyways!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

void testNewWord(string word, vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap> >* chains) {
    PeekDeque<StringWrap>* newpd = new PeekDeque<StringWrap>(100);
    newpd->pushFront(StringWrap(word));
    chains->push_back(*newpd);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){   
    vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap> >* chains = new vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap> >(); 

    string word;

    string infileName = argv[1];
    ifstream* INFILEp = new ifstream(infileName.c_str(), ios_base::in);

    while ((*INFILEp) >> word) {
        testNewWord(word, chains);

    }

    INFILEp->close();

}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Perhaps delete is being called on a null pointer? Go easy on me.

Comment: Why can't you just use a debugger and execute your program step by step? Is it really harder then asking?

Comment: I've never done that before -- I'm new to this. What should I be looking for?

Comment: for IDE with debugger. Pick any there bunch of free ones. For example Netbeans.

Comment: or, if you're on linux, use gdb. you call it with `gdb my_executable`, and then type `run` at the prompt. Once it crashes, type `backtrace` and it will tell you exactly the sequence of steps that caused the crash.

Comment: Thank you for the debugging suggestions, it looks like I've got some fiddling to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the places you use a pointer here actually need to be (nor should they be) pointers.  Instead they should be the regular object, and then passed via *references*.

Try replacing:

```
vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap> >* chains = new vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap> >();
```

With simply:

```
vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap> > chains;
```

And

```
void testNewWord(string word, vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap> >* chains) {
     PeekDeque<StringWrap>* newpd = new PeekDeque<StringWrap>(100);
```

With:

```
void testNewWord(const string& word, vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap> >& chains) {
     PeekDeque<StringWrap> newpd(100);
```

Read up more on [when you should use references vs. pointers](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/ENywvCM9/). In general with C++, only use pointers if you absolutely cannot use a reference. You'll also have to change all your `->` back to `.` because references act like they are the actual object, not a pointer to it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see you testing your `argc` param. What happens if no parameter is passed from command-line?

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be anything wrong with your code; what you are doing is perfectly legal and correct. So maybe the's something else missing from the picture, like how you are calling your code

HOWEVER - I do have one suggestion

```
    PeekDeque<StringWrap>* newpd = new PeekDeque<StringWrap>(100);
    newpd->pushFront(StringWrap(word));
    chains->push_back(*newpd);   <----
```

for the last line, the copy constructor is called and and you copy the newly created object to the vector. This is wally a waste of resources. You could replace `vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap> >* chains` with `vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>* >* chains` and hold pointers. this way you can push the pointer directly and you make use of the time spent allocating the new object.

Comment: This is a very useful suggestion based on what I'm ultimately trying to accomplish, which includes processing a lot of data!

Comment: Although you could accomplish the same thing without having to use pointers by changing the testNewWord() method to accept `PeekDeque<StringWrap>& deque` instead, filling it, and returning void. You then allocated the array above by placing an empty deque on the `chains` vector and passing `chains.back()` to the method. If you're worried about life-cycle problems, which is generally when you need to use pointers, you should try to use `shared_ptr`/`smart_ptr` instead so that memory allocation is taken care of without you having to do it manually. As written this code leaks memory like a sieve.